# Does Visual Studio provide intellisense for Angular 2 templates?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, angular

If I have Typescript component with properties, will VS autocomplete those properties in view template (separate html file)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of version 15 (preview 3) VS does not do this from what I have observed.